How do I configure my WSL to make resizeable work for tkinter or swing?
I tried to make a window in both Java and Python, both Swing and TKinter have a method that blocks resizing but it doesn't work if I'm running in WSL. Is there any way to fix this?
I tried using windows but my workspace is all in WSL, so it's inconvenient to have codes in windows only I tried in a Linux machine but it's an old laptop that's not good for continuous use. All of these work.
